# How to set socks5 proxy for Selenium ChromeDriver C# or Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, chromedriver, proxy

I am trying to setup a socks5 proxy in ChromeDriver. I have used the below code for setting that up in C#:

> var options = new ChromeOptions();
>
> var proxy = new Proxy() 
>   { Kind=ProxyKind.Manual, 
>   IsAutoDetect = false, SocksProxy = "proxy url with port number", 
>   SocksUsername =
>   username, SocksPassword = password };
>
> options.Proxy = proxy;
>
> var chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);

The above code is giving below exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'unknown error: cannot parse
>   capability: proxy from unknown error: proxyType is 'manual' but no
>   manual proxy capabilities were found

I have also tried adding socks5 proxy using `options.AddArguments` but that is also not working.

Can someone help solving this please?

Comment: This is more of a programming question, can you please try asking on stackoverflow? Not Software Quality Assurance & Testing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the nuget packages for Selenium 2.50.1 with this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
proxy = new Proxy(); 
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual; 
proxy.IsAutoDetect = false; 
proxy.HttpProxy = proxy.SslProxy = "127.0.0.1:3330"; 
options.Proxy = proxy; 
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors"); 
var chromedriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

If your proxy requires user log in, you can set the proxy with login user/password details as below:

```
options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=http://user:password@yourProxyServer.com:8080");
```